# Migration of oracle based DWH solution to GCP Bigquery

Tags: oracle, google-bigquery, database-migration, oracle-golden-gate, oracle-cdc

I'm working on the Oracle DWH solution migrate to GCP Bigquery. In the Oracle DWH, there are some tables which are having TBs in size and biggest one is the around 20TB. The large tables are more often date partitioned and we need to migrate at least 6 months to 12 months ( for some cases ) data to the Bigquery.

In the present architecture, data are streaming into DWH database via oracle Goldengate from the source database. Now customer want to replace the oracle based DWH system to GCP Bigquery and leverage GCP data analytics & BI features on it.

Please help me to understand which will be the cost effective and performance benefit approach to migrate the large database to BigQuery. We should have both features like initial load and CDC from source system to Bigquery.

Customer is looking for an Goldengate based solution but we are struggling to finalize the approach to for the initial load specially for the large tables. We had tried to export data in CSV format from our source oracle database and then load them into cloud storage as part of the initial load but exporting GBs of data into CSV is taking ages.

Need your expert guidance to understand best possible solution.

From the source table the data are exported into CSV format but this process is taking long time to export. We are migrating the large database into Bigquery and migration timeline is also very important.
Need a better yet cost effective approach for the migration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/oracle-to-bigquery) on replicating data from Oracle Database to BigQuery. Though I have not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Datastream and DMS ( Database management services) .
Incase you are looking for lift and shift then you need to go for VMware and bare metal solution . Hope this helps.